How can I get the FreeX Thermal Printer Working?
So, I've been wanting to completely move away from Windows, but the one thing preventing that is my label printer, which is FreeX (the USB-only version.)  It doesn't work at all on Linux.  It only has drivers for Mac and Windows.  I tried the generic printer drivers, which didn't work.  FreeX support is non-existent, so can't do anything there.
I have ran windows inside a virtual machine before, but that was a very painful experience.  It was very slow and laggy, and would freeze the entire PC at times.
Any ideas on what I can try to get it working?

You can try WINE or it's derivatives.
